# Spontaneous cursor transfer

Tags: cursor

Can you explain to me why after loading Ubuntu Server 16.04, when the login line appears, if wait a bit, the cursor moves to the beginning of the line and when I enter the login, the line ("hostname" login: ) starts to overwrite, I can't understand, why is this happening and can this be considered the norm? here's a video for clarity https://youtu.be/qEarK_sE-g0

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard and/or mouse?

Comment: I use notebook.

Comment: Then it's a possible problem with your trackpad or notebook application. What OS/version do you run on your notebook? Have you tried using something other than your notebook?

Comment: I think you did not quite understand what I want to say, did you watch the video to which I posted the link?

Comment: No it's not normal. I've never seen anything like your video before. Still even if cursor moves to beginning of line, can you type your normal user ID and press enter successfully?

Comment: Yes, I saw your video. I'm saying that it might be your input device... keyboard/mouse/notebook/comm application/etc.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes, I can type my username and password and enter in system

Comment: @heynnema I turned off all input devices, but the cursor is also transferred to the beginning of the line.

Comment: After you sign on and get a command prompt does the problem reoccur?

Comment: No, it is only at the very beginning, same if I just press Enter, then new lines appear
`Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS ubuntu-ru-001 tty1`
`ubuntu-ru-001 login: `
and in this case, the cursor is already in place all the time.

Comment: I was wrong, if I press Enter immediately after loading, new lines appear `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS ubuntu-ru-001 tty1` `ubuntu-ru-001 login:` but the cursor is also transferred to the beginning of the line, that is, it only happens once after loading, after a certain time

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Everything became normal only when I reinstalled Ubuntu using Legacy mode instead of UEFI